# Search Kick Problem Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm trying to use ElasticSearch via Searchkick in my Rails 5 application.

I've installed Elastic Search via the msi. It seemed to install without any issues.

However when I run any command on my model for example:

```
Record.create

NameError (uninitialized constant Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed)
```

On further inspection, it seems that ElasticSearch server doesn't run at all.
I open up the services app and I can start the elastic service but then stops pretty much straight away? Weird... No logs that I can find, nothing.

The contents of my elasticsearch.yml

```
bootstrap.memory_lock: false
cluster.name: elasticsearch
http.port: 9200
node.data: true
node.ingest: true
node.master: true
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
node.name: DESKTOP-1JP4QV8
path.data: C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\data
path.logs: C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs
transport.tcp.port: 9300
xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

Comment: Please check error log under `/var/log/elasticsearch/`, may be that help.